# delete row of database from a view list that displayed by looping

Tags: php, postgresql, row, sql-delete

I have a view list that displayed through php

```
$quedchan=pg_query("SELECT agent.agentname,  agent.onlinename, agent.channel, agentgroup.leadername FROM Agent LEFT JOIN agentgroup on agent.agentid=agentgroup.agentid where agent.channel like '%$DCH%'order by agent.channel");
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Number </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\" > Agent Name </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\"> Agent Online Name </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\"> Agent Channel </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\"> Agent Group </td>";
    echo "<td class=\"form1\" align=\"center\">  </td>";

$counttttt=1;
    While($row3=pg_fetch_array($quedchan))
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class=\"forma\" align=\"center\"> ".$counttttt++." </td>";
        echo "<td class=\"forma\"name=\"dement\" align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:10%;\"> ".$row3['agentname']." </td>";
        echo "<td class=\"forma\" align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:8%;\"> ".$row3['onlinename']." </td>";
        echo "<td class=\"forma\" align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:8%;\"> ".$row3['channel']." </td>";
        echo "<td class=\"forma\"align=\"left\"style=\"padding-left:6%;\"> ".$row3['leadername']." </td>";
        echo "<td class=\"forma\" align=\"center\"><img src=\"image\\delete.png\" width=\"20px\" height=\"20px\" style=\"padding-left:22%;cursor:pointer;\"/></td>
        </tr>";
```

And I want to make a delete function, so that the delete image of a row can delete its row. I made this by give a name for agentname row, name=\"dement\". in order to catch the value I want to delete. Im using php in another page called delete.php :

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

$dagname=$_GET['dement'];
$queda="DELETE FROM Agent where agentname='$dagname'";
$result=pg_query($queda);


if($result)
{   
    $_SESSION['delMessage11']='Selected Agent is successfully deleted!';
    header('Location: Dagent.php');
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR!"; 
}
```

?>

It doesnt work. I tried to use a reference from http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/7.html. it says I can get value of id (which I replace with agentname now) that sent from address bar. I implement it and become this

```
echo "<td class=\"form2\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"delete.php?agentname=<?    echo ".$row3['agentname'].";?>\">\"<img src=\"image\\delete.png\" onclick=\"dela();\" width=\"20px\" height=\"20px\" style=\"padding-left:22%;cursor:pointer;\"/></a></td>
                    </tr>";
```

But it doesnt work. Any help? Thank you

Comment: There's no such thing as "doesn't work". It does something and you didn't mention what.

Comment: @Jakub It doesnt delete the row

Comment: No, that's not that. Row wasn't deleted, sure. But what happened? Did you get an error thrown at you? Was the row not found in the database and not deleted? Has the query even run? Does the query work in psql?

Comment: @jakub. the query run. I got no error. the row in database is still there and not deleted. the query works well in psql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use method ="get"? it's more simple. So when the button was clicked, 'something' (based on you need) would be save in a variable and directly move on into a new page which is filled by delete queries and use `$_GET` for catch the variable(filled by 'something') for support the queries and the attributes. when you are moving on into a new page then you will see the link, it would be like this

```
DATA_NAME.php?$something.
```

I Hope this can help you. :)